# connecting two switches with different ip ranges

Tags: networking, ip, switch

I have two switches that assign different DHCP IP addresses. one assigns 192.168.0.x to devices that are connected to it and the other one assigns 10.0.0.x ip addresses. Is this the reason I cannot see devices connected to one switch from the devices that are connected to the other one? I'm trying to be able to ping all the devices no matter which switch they are connected to. is it possible? One switch is EGS7228P and the other one is a very old Cisco 24 port switch.

Comment: `I have two switches that assign different DHCP IP addresses.` - Why?

Comment: What you need is a router. That is the only way to communicate between disparate subnets.

Comment: the Cisco switch was existing and assigns 10.0.0.x range. it is also connected to internet. The new switch EGS7228P automatically assigns 192.168.0.x ip addresses to devices connected to it. I use this new switch for security cameras that need POE. I have connected the two switches with an Ethernet cable and new switch is also connected to internet. but I can't see the devices (cameras) connected to this switch from the devices that are on my original cisco switch

Answer (score 1):

> one [switch] assigns 192.168.0.x to devices that are connected to it and the other one assigns 10.0.0.x ip addresses. Is this the reason I cannot see devices connected to one switch from the devices that are connected to the other one?

Yes.

If you don't have a router all your devices must have ip-addresses in the same subnet for them to be able to reach each other over TCP/IP.

(The switches themselves must also be connected, obviously.)

> I'm trying to be able to ping all the devices no matter which switch they are connected to. is it possible?

Yes, once you set up a router.

Alternatively, change the DHCP ranges so each switch assigns ip-addresses from a different part of the same subnet.

Or configure one switch to relay DHCP requests to the other so all devices get ip-addresses from a single DHCP server.

Comment: thanks for the help. Here is the manual for the new switch. can you tell me how to relay DHCP on this switch to get IP addresses from my Cisco switch? I don't find anything regarding DHCP setting in management console: http://www.engeniustech.com/resources/EGS7228P-user_manual.pdf

Comment: the Cisco switch was existing and assigns 10.0.0.x range. it is also connected to internet. The new switch EGS7228P automatically assigns 192.168.0.x ip addresses to devices connected to it. I use this new switch for security cameras that need POE. I have connected the two switches with an Ethernet cable and new switch is also connected to internet. but I can't see the devices (cameras) connected to this switch from the devices that are on my original cisco switch

Answer (score 1):

Check Page 14 of the manual. It explains the steps you need to do on a network that already has DHCP. If you turn off DHCP in the new switch (as described there) all devices will get Adresses in the original range from the cisco switch and you can see them all as its one network. If you need to keep networks separate, a router is the way to go as already suggested.